# How to add a parameter to my URL without reinitializing the component associated with the route?

Tags: angular

I have two routes in my routing component (that are relevant to the question):

```
{
    path: 'curation/:documentId/drug-approval/:findingId',
    component: DrugApprovalComponent
}, {
    path: 'curation/:documentId/drug-approval',
    component: DrugApprovalComponent
}
```

Initially users enter on the 2nd route, fill in a form and hit save, at which point a request is made to the back-end and I get back a findingId.

I want to add the finding id to the URL (so that if/when users refresh the page, they still get the same form).

Simply navigating the the route resets my form because the component is reinitalized:

```js
this.router.navigate([data.findingId], { relativeTo: this.route});
```

I tried using `{skipLocationChange: true}` but that only skips adding a new history state and my component is reinit.

I also tried with the location API (as was advised in similar questions) but that just seems 'hacky' to me and also, the `createUrlTree` function does not take into account my root (base url) which I don't want to hardcode sice it's based on build params.

```js
this.router.createUrlTree(
     [
         '/curation',
         this.documentId,
         'drug-approval',
         data.findingId
     ]
 ).toString()  // This does not contain the base url
```

I also tried to use a RouteReuseStrategy but I'm apparently missing something because that's not working either (I already added it as a provider in my main module).

*param-change-route-reuse-strategy.ts*

```js
export class ParamChangeRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
    shouldDetach() {
        return false;
    }

    shouldAttach() {
        return false;
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        if (future.firstChild && curr.firstChild) {
            if (future.firstChild.component) {
                if (componentsForReuse.includes(future.firstChild.component['name'])) {
                    if (future.firstChild.routeConfig.path.includes(curr.firstChild.routeConfig.path)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    store() {}

    retrieve() {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

So this is where I'm at right now. I think I could also do it with the location API but I'm fairly convinced there's an "Angular Way" and I want to use that if possible.

Comment: Have you tried adding `skipLocationChange` to navigate options? Not sure if it only skips adding a new history state or if it also skips reinitializing the component.

Comment: I did. It only skips adding a new history state. I'll edit my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to `Router.navigate`, you invoke the component set in your `routing component`.

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. [Not recommended]. Save the state of the component (in a service, or whatever) and, onInit, if the url has not changed, restore the state.
2. [Recommended]. Simple change the URL, without triggering a new component rendering:

You should try something like:

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common'; 
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({...})
class WhateverComponent {
  constructor(
    private location: Location,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ){}

  doThing(data) {
    const url = this
        .router
        .createUrlTree([data.findingId], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
        .toString();

     this.location.go(url); // Changes the browser's URL to a normalized version of a given URL, and pushes a new item onto the platform's history.

     // OR
     // this.location.replaceState(url); // Changes the browser's URL to a normalized version of the given URL, and replaces the top item on the platform's history stack.

  }
}
```

References:

- https://angular.io/api/common/Location
- https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createurltree

Comment: Is this the "angular way" because I would have expected to be able to use the router.navigate in some way, shape or form? Also, the solution you propose does not take into account my root path (base url).

Comment: You can consider this as an "angular way". You're not messing with the DOM, you're not using the `window` object, you're not using any webclient API directly. I'm not aware of any method in the `router` that wouldn't call the component's `onInit`